# Stuck in a while-loop in GNU/SU (seismic unix)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-12.04, bash-scripting, infinite-loop

I'm new to programming. I have this loop (it's part of a data processing script) and I have it all good until this section cause I can't figure out why it stay looping in the second 'while'

Take a look:

> .../bash
>   cdpmin=1800
>   cdpmax=2100
>   dcdp=100
>   cdp=$cdpmin
>
> while [ $cdp -le $cdpmax ]
>   do
>   echo $cdp
>       ok=false
>
> > while [ ok=false ]
> >         do
> >     .
> >     .
> >     .
> >      echo "It's correct? (y/n)" | tr -d "\012" >/dev/tty
> >             read response
> >
> > > ```
> > > case $response in  
> > >     n*)   
> > >        ok=false ;;  
> > >     *)   
> > >        ok=true ;;  
> > > esac
> > > ```
> >
> > done
>
> cdp=$[$cdp+$dcdp]
>
> done

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't comparing what you think you are, you are comparing the literal "ok" with the word "false".  Instead, you need to compare the variable `$ok` with `false`.

With that adjustment, it would look like:

```
ok="false"
while [[ "$ok" = "false" ]]
do
    ...
done
```

I believe you will also run into an error with `cdp=$[$cdp + $dcpd]`, in bash, addition usually looks like:

```
cdp=$(($cdp + $dcpd))
```

A tip:  Since the condition for the loop you were stuck in was `ok=false`, it is clear that the issue is in the condition not changing as you expect.  This is one of those easy to overlook issues though that is a face palm after the fact.  Any time I run into these, I go for a walk or something to take my mind off it.  More often than not, when I come back - the issue is obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the "$ok" correction! Nonetheless I had it in the original script so that's not the problem. :/ I just realized that the words "false" and "true" were bold, so i guessed they both were functions then I changed them for "1" and "0" but it didnt work either.

P.S.: this syntax addition "cdp=$[$cdp + $dcpd]" does work. :)

Comment: I think technically, they should be quoted for all of those, so `ok="false"` and then `while [ "$ok" = "false" ] ... n) ok="false"` etc.  Try that.  Also, in new shells - the `[[ condition ]]` is supposedly more powerful due to globbing (I think).  It's strange that doesn't work for you since using what you posted with those changes works fine for me....

Comment: So if you use what I posted '$cdp' reaches "2100"? // I've put 'echo=$cdp' cause I wanna check the loop was going well but it always print "1800" which is the first value... so I guess it's stuck in the second while cause never add the new value and keep asking me "It's correct (y/n)"

Comment: See the second part of my answer as to why that probably is.  Did you update the addition in bash?

Comment: No, I didn't update it. // with the second part of your answer (which was a little confusing to me) did you mean to use "[[--]]"? I've used it in both while-loops but nothing changed. :/ (Guess you've noticed I'm not a native english speaker)

Comment: No, square brackets are used for comparisons, you need perens for addition.

Comment: oh! Ok. Thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't work yet, this loop its getting really annoying... thanks for the comprehension.

Comment: Hi! I've just found the error (face palm moment haha)... I should have put a whitespace frame for the "=" in the while condition. // It was not necessary to quote false either true. //  
I also tried the command "let" for the addition and it worked too. Thank you. :)